# Azure Data Lake Gen 1 vs Gen 2

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake

Recently Azure [announced](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-simplifies-cloud-analytics/) Data Lake Gen 2 preview. As far as I know the main difference between Gen 1 and Gen 2  (in terms of functionality) is the Object Store and File System access over the same data at the same time. Other differences would be the price, available location etc. Can anyone explain what are the other key differences between Gen 1 and Gen 2?

Comment: ADLS Gen 1 retirement is announced by Microsoft, FAQs including migration procedures can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/answers/answers/281143/view.html

Answer (score 9):

Basically, think of gen2 as a superset of gen1 plus  all of the best parts of blob storage: tiers, HDFS and  object store API's and presumably the ability to efficiently handle the management of over 35K files and efficiently dealing with many small sizes and more trickle write type operations.. plus its cheaper.

I'm trying to get some clarity on a few specifics but not finding much in the meantime try these links:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/a-closer-look-at-azure-data-lake-storage-gen2/

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/data-lake-storage/introduction

Answer (score 5):

Azure data lake storage Gen2 is a super set of Azure data lake Gen 1. It also called as a "no-compromise data lake" by Microsoft. Gen 2 extends Azure blob storage capabilities and it is best optimized for analytics workloads. It can store data once and access via existing blob storage and HDFS-compliant file system interfaces with no programming changes or data copying when doing database operations since it supports atomic file and folder operations. 
At present, it is only available in West US 2 and West Central US data centers. But it will be expanded into other data centers in the near future according to Microsoft.

Answer (score 4):

There is a Microsoft [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-migrate-gen1-to-gen2#gen1-vs-gen2-capabilities) that talks about the the differences. For Example:

**Data Organization:**

Gen1

- Hierarchical namespace, File and folder support.

Gen2

- Hierarchical namespace, container, file and folder support

**Geo-redundancy:**

Gen1

- LRS.

Gen2

- LRS, ZRS, GRS, RA-GRS.

**Ecosystem:**

Gen1

- HDInsight (3.6), Azure Databricks (3.1 and above), SQL DW, ADF

Gen2

- HDInsight (3.6, 4.0), Azure Databricks (5.1 and above), SQL DW, ADF

Answer (score 1):

Adding to below differences, when using ADF to connect to Azure data lake analytics storage account we need to choose Gen1 for Linked Service and for blob or storage account we need to choose Gen2.

Answer (score 0):

Main difference is of U-SQL(Gen1) and T-SQL(Gen2).

The difference between U-SQL & T-SQL is that PolyBase extends T-SQL onto unstructured data (files) via a schematized view that allows writing T-SQL against these files, while U-SQL natively operates on unstructured data and virtualizes access to other SQL data sources via a built-in EXTRACT expression that allows you to schematize unstructured data on the fly without having to create a metadata object for it.

In addition of it, Gen2 also supports ZRS, GRS, RA-GRS along with LRS.

Answer (score -1):

Azure gen1 interact with Hdfs. It supports for few reasons but storage account support all regions and both r integrated and Microsoft release new version called zen2
Zen2 it's a combination of blob storage and zen1
That means zen2 build on top of azure blob storage
If u want to create zen2 account need to go for a storage account  go to advance enable gen2

Comment: What do you mean by zen?

Answer (score -1):

Difference Between ADLS Gen1 and Gen2
Here are some differences between Azure Data Lake Storage (ADLS) Gen1 and Gen2:

1. Hadoop compatible: ADLS Gen1 is based on Hadoop Distributed File System (HDFS), while ADLS Gen2 is built on top of Azure Blob Storage. This makes ADLS Gen2 more scalable and cost-effective, as it can leverage the capabilities of Blob Storage.
2. Namespace and hierarchy: ADLS Gen1 has a flat namespace, while ADLS Gen2 has a hierarchical namespace. ADLS Gen2 uses directories to organize data, which provides a more efficient way to manage large amounts of data.
3. Security: ADLS Gen1 uses access control lists (ACLs) for authorization, while ADLS Gen2 uses role-based access control (RBAC) and Azure Active Directory (AAD) authentication. This makes it easier to manage access to data, especially in large organizations.
4. Data Lake Analytics: ADLS Gen1 integrates with Azure Data Lake Analytics, a cloud-based analytics service that can process big data using U-SQL, a language that combines SQL and C#. ADLS Gen2 also supports Data Lake Analytics, but it uses Apache Spark instead of U-SQL.
5. Pricing: ADLS Gen2 has a lower cost of ownership compared to ADLS Gen1, as it uses Blob Storage and has a more efficient architecture. However, ADLS Gen1 is still a good choice for organizations that are heavily invested in Hadoop.
   Overall, ADLS Gen2 is a more modern and flexible solution for storing and analyzing big data, while ADLS Gen1 is a more traditional solution that is still used by many organizations.
   ADLS Gen2 = Azure Blob Storage + ADLS Gen1